# SharePoint 2010 SSRS Report Manage Processing Options cannot click OK to save changes

Tags: reporting-services, cache

When attempting to change Data Refresh Options for an SSRS report I'm unable to click the OK button to save changes.  The button appears to press in the browser, however no event fires.  Its almost as if the OK button is not wired to any JavaScript function.

Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue was related to javascript restrictions in my company's Internet Explorer.  I've been using FireFox to browse our local intranet and haven't had this issue since.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same problem.

Do you see any red warning message in any section of the Manage Processing Options?

For example, I couldn't click OK because I had a warning in the History Snapshot Options section. I ticked off the "Allow history...", the message went away and I was able to click OK.